# Rails data remote form, not working after show hide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag '/offer.js', :id => 'offer', :remote => true do %>
// some inputs
<% end %>
```

The remote form works fine until I do I show hide with jQuery it does not create a ajax call. Why is that and how to fix this?

In the offer partial:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
             url: $('#next').data('link'), //your server side script
             type: 'GET',
             success: function (data) {
                $("#step2").html(data);
            },
                error: function (responseObject) {
                    alert("der opstod en fejl");
                }
         });
});
```

After I have clicked on the next button, the offer form is not longer doing an ajax call.

Comment: not enough information.  How are you triggering the submit?  What kind of javascript is returned from `offer.js`?

Comment: It renders a partial. The form should be submitted via a ajax call when using data remote, but it dose not when doing a show hide which a need to a multistep form.

Comment: I have also tried `$("#offer").trigger("submit.rails");` and it does just go to the `/offer.js` and does not create an ajax call.

Comment: you really have to show more code.  there's a mistake somewhere and just describing what it should be doing doesn't help in spotting it.

Comment: It seems like after I do I ajax call in the partial the form_for data remote does not work..

Comment: I have found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when doing a ajax call with jQuery the action should be set to `render :layout => false` else it will load the layout and your form_form data remote will not work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#next').live('click', function () {

   //Place your ajax request code here

});
```